# How to target a specific element using javascript

Tags: javascript

After a CLICK on the taskYes icon, i need to get the value on the input with the inputMins class

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <span class="taskTitle">
        <input id="newInput" type="text" /> 
        <button class="taskYes"></button>
    </span>

    <span class="taskMinutes">
        <input class="col-md-2 inputMins" type="text" />
    </span>
</form>
```

Can you help me saying what is the best way to target my input?

I've tried this but ... without success :

```
$(".taskYes").click(function(){
    var valeurTime = $(this).parent().next("span").val();
    alert(valeurTime);
});
```

Comment: So what you asking is when you click button it should give you the id of the input or what ?

Comment: Hello :) I need to get the value on the input with the inputMins class (the last input on my code)

Comment: I think you need to give it a value first like <input class="col-md-2 inputMins" type="text" value="alan" />

Comment: Nah, the value is given by the user before he clicks on the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my browser this code is working, please send me your result!

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        function init() {
            console.log("here");
            $(".taskYes").click(function(evt){
var value = $(evt.target).parent().next('span').find('.inputMins').val();
alert(value);
});
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<form method="post" action="">
    <span class="taskTitle">
        <input id="newInput" type="text" />
        <button class="taskYes"></button>
    </span>

    <span class="taskMinutes">
        <input class="col-md-2 inputMins" type="text" />
    </span>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jQuery? Or VanillaJS?

Jquery Solution:

```
 $('.inputMins').val()
```

VanillaJS Solution:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('inputMins')[0].value
```

Comment: I don't think this works because he doesn't have a value on the input. I mean how can you get a value on the input with the inputMins class when there is no value.

Comment: Yes it works! The value of inputMins is the text inside of input element.

Comment: That works but the problem is that i got a lot of input with the inputMins class.

I need to target the input with the inputMins class on the form where the button is clicked

Comment: Ok, for that you'll need to catch clickEvent

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work :/ Check my JS code on the question

Answer (score 0):

And now the full implementation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function checkTaskMinutes() {
            debugger;
            alert(document.getElementsByClassName('inputMins')[0].value);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<form method="post" action="">
    <span class="taskTitle">
        <input id="newInput" type="text" />
        <button class="taskYes" onclick="checkTaskMinutes()"></button>
    </span>

    <span class="taskMinutes">
        <input class="col-md-2 inputMins" type="text" />
    </span>
</form>


</html>
```

Comment: Hello :)

I have to give this precision :

i got a lot of input with the inputMins class. I need to target the input with the inputMins class on the form where the button is clicked

Comment: For that, add a unique id like `<input id="yes" class="col-md-2 inputMins" type="text" />` and use `document.getElementById('yes').value` or if you are using jQuery `$("#yes").val()`

Comment: That won't work for me because i will have a lot of input and i can't give a function by input, that will be too much

Comment: Try this: 
`$(".taskYes").click(function(evt){
    var valeurTime = $(evt.currentTarget).closest(".inputMins").val();
    alert(valeurTime);
});`

Comment: I got a "undefined" alert

Answer (score 0):

is more simple! Try this:

```
$(".taskYes").click(function(evt){
var value = $(evt.target).parent().next('span').find('.inputMins').val();
console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Hello :)
The console.log result is "undefined"